# Android and game levels

Tags: android

I have a fully working canvas and it implements everything that I need to create my first Android game.

I call it like this...

```
public class GameScreen extends Activity {
    // CALLED WHEN THE ACTIVITY IS FIRST CREATED
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // SET THE GAME CANVAS TO DISPLAY
        setContentView(new GameCanvas(this));
    }  
}
```

The problem I am having is how I should load levels into the canvas? I have also created a menu with which users can choose a level to play, but upon choosing, how can I load that particular level onto the canvas and all the logic etc?

I am new to Android so forgive me if the question is very basic.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Have you considered checking out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ? The community there specializes in game questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question is impossible to answer effectively.  It's going to completely depend on how your levels are saved, what kind of level loading logic you have, how you have structured your project...